# train a model with mulitple input dataset not numpy arrays

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset, tensor

Given this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

a_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
a_valid_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))

b_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
b_valid_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))

a_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,4), name=‘a_input’)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(a_input)
x = keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)

b_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,4), name=‘b_input’)
y = keras.layers.Flatten()(b_input)
y = keras.layers.Dense(5)(y)

z = keras.layers.concatenate(\[x,y\])
z = keras.layers.Dense(2)(z)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=\[a_input, b_input\], outputs=z)

model.compile(loss=‘mse’, optimizer=‘adam’, metrics=\[‘mae’\])
model.fit(\[a_train_ds, b_train_ds\], validation_data=\[a_valid_ds, b_valid_ds\], epochs=1)
```

I tried to train the model but got the following error:

I have tried to train this model, but I got the following error:
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: ( containing values of types {“”}),

Answer (score 0):

The train and test data as well as train and test labels - all need to be **Numpy arrays**.

Numpy arrays and lists shouldn't be confused with.

Hence, the following code should be good enough to go with :

```
x_train = np.asarray(x_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)

x_valid = np.asarray(x_valid)
y_valid = np.asarray(y_valid)
```

If this solves your error, do give a like or let me know in the comments if anything else is required. Happy learning!

Comment: does not work for a large dataset (60GO), I got out of memory error;